# Execute .php and .html via form

Tags: php, html

I have this contact form:

```
<form class="contactform" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phonenumber(optional)</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="telephone"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>E-mail</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Your question or comment</td></tr>
        <tr><td><textarea name="comment"></textarea></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type='submit' name='sending' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

And when the user clicks submit, it goes to a php script which sends the contact form details to me, which happends at `action="contact.php"` But I would like a separated html page, a "thanks for you question" page. How would I execute 2 files, via `action` or otherwise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your contact form has done what it needs to do, have it redirect to a thankyou page.

contact.php

```
// Your stuff here
header("location: /thank-you.php"); // Assumes thank-you.php is in server root
exit();
```

thank-you.php

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Thank you</h1>
<p>Stuff stuff stuff!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you've finished processing your form data in contact.php redirect to your thankyou page: `header('Location: '.'thankyou.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `print("thanks for you question");` at the end of your contact.php after you have processed the data or before it, however you like. You cannot send this to 2 different pages/files.

Comment: The file where the .php is in, is really old. Back when website's where created via `tables, tr, td`. So the php breaks the file's images and positions.

Answer (score 0):

Add `header("location:thankyou.html");` in your contact.php file after the processing of request is complete.